# How do I quickly factorize quadratic equations?

Tags: factoring

Whenever I have to factorize an equation I usually just look for the common factors and then just work form there. However, I was wondering whether there is a quicker way to get the factorized form.

**Edit**

How to quickly factorize **quadratic equations** of the form
$$
ax^2 + by + c = 0,
$$
where $a,b,c\in\Bbb{R}$.

Simple example: Factorize $x^2 + 3x - 4 = 0$

Help would be appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: This question feels incredibly general. Can you try to explain in a bit more detail what you are asking, perhaps with some examples?

Comment: @Phill I added some changes.

Comment: Are you familiar with the quadratic formula?

Comment: Take a look at completing the square method. This should be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square

Comment: @Phill I am familiar with it but doesn't that just give you the solution?

Comment: @anonymous It does, I was just trying to see what kind of answer you were looking for. One way is to try substituting in some numbers for x. If you get zero as the answer, then that is a root

Comment: The way to factorize quadratic (or any) expressions quickly is to factorize so many of them that you get a feel for them. Do a few hundred, then you'll be real good at it.

Comment: 0. We know if irreducible $\frac{p}{q}$ is a root of $ax^2+bx+c$, then $p|c, q|a$. Hm, next follows for $a=1$. 1. Factorize $c$ into product of two numbers. In the example above $x_1x_2=4=2\cdot 2=1\cdot 4$. 2. Try to combine the factors of $c$ such way that $x_1\pm x_2 = \pm b$. In the example above: $2\pm 2=0\hbox{ or }4\neq 3$, $4\pm 1=5\hbox{ or }3$. We got $3$. The roots are $(\pm1,\pm4)$ 3. Signs. $-4=x_1x_2\to$ sign differs. $(1,-4)$  or $(4,-1)$. $x_1+x_2=-b=-3$ the greater one($4$) is "$-$". The roots are $(-4,1)$, $(x+4)(x-1)$ is the form. Done. @anonymous

Comment: Transform equation into $x^2+(b/a)x+(c/a)=0$. Then find 2 numbers $ i $ and $ j$ where $i+j = -(b/a)$, $ij=(c/a)$. Then the expression simplifies to $(x-i)(x-j)=0$. Of course, as Gerry Myerson mentioned, practice makes perfect:)

Comment: You want $a,b,c \in \mathbb Z$, not $\mathbb R$. Otherwise the question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Here's a helpful hint (assuming $a,b,c$ are integers): If $b^2-4ac$ is a perfect square, then the equation can be factorised into terms of the form $px+q$, where $p$ and $q$ are integers. Otherwise it can't. So you can quickly check to see whether it's worthwhile trying to factorise an equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way, I call it middle-split.

Taking your equation under the spotlight

$x^2+3x-4=0$

Think of 2 numbers $p,q$ such that
$p+q=3$
and $pq=-4$

That yields $4,-1$ as one of the pair.

So, we split the equation from the middle such that
$x^2-x+4x-4=0$

Now, it is easy to factorize.
$x(x-1)+4(x-1)=0$

$(x+4)(x-1)=0$

So, either $x=-4$ or $x=1$

Quite often this trick will work. But, always emphasis that you use the quadratic formula, which removes the "guess-work" involved, and relies completely on computation.

$$x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Answer (score 1):

For $x^2+3x-4$, it should be obvious that $4\times(-1)=-4$, and $4+(-1)=3$. Basically you want to look for two numbers $x,y$ such that $x\times y$ gives you the coefficient of $x$, and $x+y$ gives you the coefficient of the constant. The only way to be quick at this is to practise a lot.

Also, use WolframAlpha when you are sleepy.

Comment: You got those wrong! What's important here is: $4 + (-1) = 3$, and $4 \times (-1) = -4$. (Your equations arise when factorising $x^2-4x+3$.)

Comment: @TonyK oops sorry, i'll fix it